# login a user which the input name is different of the table field name

Tags: laravel

I have a question I am trying to login a user with a pseudo / password
in my table the field is 'pseudo' but in my form the input name is username 
here is my code to login my user

```
protected function login(Request $request){

    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        dd('hello');
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->$this->redirectTo();
    }
    else{

    }

}
```

and my user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'pseudo', 'mail', 'password','active','confirm_password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function games(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Game');
    }

}
```

If I rename my input name = username to input name = pseudo it is working but I wanted to keep my input name with username

```
            <div class="form-item form-group">
                <input name="username" id="username" type="text" value="" placeholder="Pseudo" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item form-group">
                <input name="password" id='password' type="password" value="" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to overwrite username() method

```
public function username(){
   return 'pseudo';
}
```

and then your input change the "username" input to "pseudo"

```
<div class="form-item form-group">
            <input name="pseudo" id="pseudo" type="text" value="" placeholder="Pseudo" required>
        </div>
```

dont forget to edit login() method as well

```
$credentials = $request->only('pseudo', 'password');
```

Comment: i wanted to keep my input name ='username'

Comment: I think it will works although you dont change your input, just try my solution without changing your input. I mean just try to overwrite username() method. Ignore other code

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
$username = $request['username'];
$request['psuedo'] = $username;

$credentials = $request->only('psuedo', 'password');
```